# Falling Mapple Leaves PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to show falling mapple leaves on a slide of ppt. Its that achievable ? If yes how ?
I did try to google but not able to figure out.

Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's achievable with animation. I think it will be more difficult to implement this with VBA. Insert your mapple leave picture, and go to "*Animation*" Tab and choose Custom Path. You can draw the path of a falling leave.

Quick ugly example :

[image]